# String-db locally downloaded

Tags: proteins, database, protein-interaction, network

I need a ppi network of cancer and it should have `200k` to `300k` proteins (nodes)
As the web inteface don't allow more than 2000 proteins to be visualized . I have downloaded the `protein_links` of homosapiens from the download section . 
It has `11353058` link which means 11353058 interaction .
The downloaded file is a `.txt` How do we do  to extract `cancer` interaction from this huge set ?
What are the different ways to manipulate this file .

Comment: I dare say it's outside of my realm to do network analyses, but I also don't believe it's possible to just say *cancer* and pull out a network. This is especially so since melanoma will differ widely from renal-cell carcinoma, lung cancer and so forth. Perhaps this paper will help you ([ref](https://www.nature.com/articles/ncomms14356)).

Comment: Actually I don't really care about the type of cancer ,as far as I'm concerned with the data , the amount of data  I need a network of 200k of whatever type of cancer or any other disease from that file that's all I'm asking for And thank you for the paper @CMosychuk

Comment: It is more of data necessity than it is of biological , proteomics need